# manjaro linux elixir logger crash

Tags: elixir, manjaro

After updating the core of the manjaro from version 4.16 to 4.17, the elixir 1.5 logger stopped working

```
elixir -v
=SUPERVISOR REPORT==== 12-Jul-2018::16:29:19.697604 ===
    supervisor: {local,'Elixir.Logger.Supervisor'}
    errorContext: start_error
    reason: noproc
    offender: [{pid,undefined},
               {id,'Elixir.Logger.ErrorHandler'},
               {mfargs,
                   {'Elixir.Logger.Watcher',start_link,
                       [{error_logger,'Elixir.Logger.ErrorHandler',
                            {true,false,500}}]}},
               {restart_type,permanent},
               {shutdown,5000},
               {child_type,worker}]
=CRASH REPORT==== 12-Jul-2018::16:29:19.702313 ===
  crasher:
    initial call: application_master:init/4
    pid: <0.81.0>
    registered_name: []
    exception exit: {{shutdown,
                         {failed_to_start_child,'Elixir.Logger.ErrorHandler',
                             noproc}},
                     {'Elixir.Logger.App',start,[normal,[]]}}
      in function  application_master:init/4 (application_master.erl, line 138)
    ancestors: [<0.80.0>]
    message_queue_len: 1
    messages: [{'EXIT',<0.82.0>,normal}]
    links: [<0.80.0>,<0.42.0>]
    dictionary: []
    trap_exit: true
    status: running
    heap_size: 376
    stack_size: 27
    reductions: 193
  neighbours:

=INFO REPORT==== 12-Jul-2018::16:29:19.703351 ===
    application: logger
    exited: {{shutdown,
                 {failed_to_start_child,'Elixir.Logger.ErrorHandler',noproc}},
             {'Elixir.Logger.App',start,[normal,[]]}}
    type: temporary
Erlang/OTP 21 [erts-10.0.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe]

Elixir 1.5.3
```

at the same time, version 1.6 works fine

```
elixir -v
Erlang/OTP 21 [erts-10.0.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe]

Elixir 1.6.6 (compiled with OTP 19)

OS:
Linux mvalitov-pc 4.17.4-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Jul 3 18:11:09 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I use asdf for version control.

I tried to remove and reinstall the elixir, but to no avail
asdf uninstall elixir 1.5
asdf install elixir 1.5

maybe someone has an idea how to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason seems to be that OTP 21 is not yet officially supported, as explained in this [**GitHub issue**](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/7638).